# Visual Studio 2013 and Git 2.4

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have installed the [Git for windows 2.4.1 release candidate (64bit)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.2.windows.1/Git-2.4.2.1-release-candidate-64-bit.exe)

After this installation, in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4), the Git integration seems unable to find the `git.exe`. At least, that is my guess when it shows the following, since I already have Git installed, but in a new folder (`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`):

[image: Install 3rd-party Git command prompt tools]

Is there any way I can make Visual Studio recognize the new location of `git.exe`?

Or can I completely disregard this warning? The git integration in Visual Studio seems to work anyway.

Comment: Could it be a problem with PATH variable?

Comment: `git.exe` is definitely on the path.

Comment: Seeing this now with Visual Studio 2015 and Git for Windows 2.5.2 (not sure, but everything seems to be working even with this message).

Comment: I have the same with Visual Studio 2015 and Git (Windows) 2.6.2, not sure what the deal is, everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore this issue.  Git for Windows 2.x changed the registry key locations that Visual Studio uses to try to locate it.

However this message is simply informational; Visual Studio does not require Git for Windows to manage your repositories.

Upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (or better) will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried 2 things that seemed to have solved the issue. I'm not sure which of the two really solved the issue

1) I checked my paths and made sure git was only in C:\Program Files\Git and removed the C:\Program Files (x86)\Git from the path through the environment variables

2) I then did a repair on visual studio through Control Panel / Add Remove

The problem went away